# PHP MySQL error , unable to register and post params to local server on XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I am following this tutorial : https://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

I m getting : 
{"error":true,"error_msg":"Required parameters (name, email or password) is missing!"}
on running the register.php on POSTMAN with POST and it gives the same error on RAW.

the only error I get when I put :http://localhost/android_login_api/register.php on POSTMAN with POST method is:
{"error":true,"error_msg":"Required parameters (name, email or password) is missing!"}

and on giving param value : http://localhost/android_login_api/register.php?name=arnav&email=arnav.kaushal800@gmail.com&password=password .
I get a Fatal error: on boolean for method prepare().

Below are all the files of php scripts

Config.php

```
<?php


$db_host = "localhost";
$db_username = "root";
$db_name = "android_api";

@mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username") or die("Could not connect to MySQL");
@mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die("Could not find database");

?>
```

DB_Connect.php

```
    <?php
class DB_Connect {
    private $conn;

    // Connecting to database
    public function connect() {
        require_once 'include/Config.php';

        // Connecting to mysql database
        //$this->conn = new mysqli($db_host,$db_username,$db_name);
        $this->conn = (@mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username") or die("Could not connect to MySQL"))&&(@mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die("Could not find database"));


        // return database handler
        return $this->conn;             


    }
}

?>
```

DB_Functions.php

```
 <?php

class DB_Functions {

    private $conn;

    // constructor
    function __construct() {
        require_once 'include/DB_Connect.php';
        // connecting to database
        $db = new Db_Connect();
        $this->conn = $db->connect();
    }

    // destructor
    function __destruct() {

    }

    /**
     * Storing new user
     * returns user details
     */
    public function storeUser($name, $email, $password) {
        $uuid = uniqid('', true);
        $hash = $this->hashSSHA($password);
        $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"]; // encrypted password
        $salt = $hash["salt"]; // salt

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users(unique_id, name, email, encrypted_password, salt, created_at) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW())");
        $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $uuid, $name, $email, $encrypted_password, $salt);
        $result = $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();

        // check for successful store
        if ($result) {
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?");
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
            $stmt->execute();
            $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
            $stmt->close();

            return $user;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get user by email and password
     */
    public function getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password) {

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?");

        $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);

        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
            $stmt->close();

            // verifying user password
            $salt = $user['salt'];
            $encrypted_password = $user['encrypted_password'];
            $hash = $this->checkhashSSHA($salt, $password);
            // check for password equality
            if ($encrypted_password == $hash) {
                // user authentication details are correct
                return $user;
            }
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check user is existed or not
     */
    public function isUserExisted($email) {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT email from users WHERE email = ?");

        $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);

        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->store_result();

        if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
            // user existed 
            $stmt->close();
            return true;
        } else {
            // user not existed
            $stmt->close();
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Encrypting password
     * @param password
     * returns salt and encrypted password
     */
    public function hashSSHA($password) {

        $salt = sha1(rand());
        $salt = substr($salt, 0, 10);
        $encrypted = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);
        $hash = array("salt" => $salt, "encrypted" => $encrypted);
        return $hash;
    }

    /**
     * Decrypting password
     * @param salt, password
     * returns hash string
     */
    public function checkhashSSHA($salt, $password) {

        $hash = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);

        return $hash;
    }

}

?>
```

Register.php

```
<?php

require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();

// json response array
$response = array("error" => FALSE);

if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {

    // receiving the post params
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    // check if user is already existed with the same email
    if ($db->isUserExisted($email)) {
        // user already existed
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "User already existed with " . $email;
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // create a new user
        $user = $db->storeUser($name, $email, $password);
        if ($user) {
            // user stored successfully
            $response["error"] = FALSE;
            $response["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
            $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
            $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
            $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
            $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // user failed to store
            $response["error"] = TRUE;
            $response["error_msg"] = "Unknown error occurred in registration!";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    }
} else {
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Required parameters (name, email or password) is missing!";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Even after passing all the parameters , I still get the following error:
{"error":true,"error_msg":"Required parameters (name, email or password) is missing!"}.

Comment: in register.php try `var_dump($_POST);` what's the output?

Comment: array(1) { ["------WebKitFormBoundaryZ92bfuT2eROzniDs
Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name"]=>
  string(284) ""name"

Arnav

------WebKitFormBoundaryZ92bfuT2eROzniDs
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="email"

arnav.kaushal800@gmail.com
------WebKitFormBoundaryZ92bfuT2eROzniDs
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="password"

password
------WebKitFormBoundaryZ92bfuT2eROzniDs--
"
}
{"error":true,"error_msg":"Required parameters (name, email or password) is missing!"}

Comment: so its getting the params , the name , email and password but getting the same error again

Comment: **WARNING**: Using the error-suppressing YOLO operator (`@`) obscures problems with your code and makes debugging issues like this a whole lot more complicated. That's a tool of last resort and should only be used in exceptional circumstances. You should display an error message for the user, log a problem, initiate some kind of retry, or all of these things in conjunction.

Comment: **WARNING**: Do not use the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface which was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Here parameters are **NOT** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and this has severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) in this code. Escape **any** and all user data, especially from `$_POST` or `$_GET`.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: i know all that and thats why i am following a tutorial but can anybody tell me whats wrong with the code. Why does the error keep getting a true value and hence displaying : " {"error":true,"error_msg":"Required parameters (name, email or password) is missing!"}."